# How Do I Set Up Listview in WPF to Respond to Enter as well as MouseClick?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a WPF listview from which I make selections using "SelectionChanged" in my XAML.  My backing code is in C#.  The app works fine.  I'd like to also make selections by pressing Enter when a particular row is highlighted, to obtain the same result as mouse-clicking on that entry.

I tried setting up a KeyUp event in my XAML and checking for when e.Key is "Return" in the backing code, and this too works fine, as far as it goes.  The problem is that there's no way I can see to pick up what row in the listview I was on when I pressed Enter: SelectedIndex is -1, and SelectedItem is null, so no selection apparently occurred; all this shows is that I was in the listview when I pressed Enter.

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this?  I'm relatively new to WPF, so please be specific in your response.

Comment: Hi, please provide your code, it will be way easier =)

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedIndex` is directly linked to the `SelectionChanged` event and only changes when the item is selected.

You should use something like the `ListViewItemMouseHoverEvent` to get the index for the enter KeyUp event.

```
YourListViewItemType item;
private void ListView1_ItemMouseHover(Object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e) {
    item = e.Item;
}
private void Page_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(item == null) return;
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        // Do something with highlighted item
    }
}
```

Something like this should work

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, using the up and down arrows on the listview (when it's in focus) DOES set SelectedIndex.  Not sure why I didn't pick up on that before, but once I found that out, it was a simple matter to retrieve the record from my observable collection and parse it out.  I ended up coding a Keyboard.KeyUp event in my XAML and checking what key was pressed in my event handler, e.g., C or Enter means change, D or Delete means delete, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a button in a ListView
It should work with a text block
You just need to get the DataContext

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
GabeLib.SearchItem srchItem = (GabeLib.SearchItem)btn.DataContext;
```